# Negative moments of variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Let $f_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be independent Steinhaus random variables, i.e. variables which are  uniformly distributed on the complex unit circle. Let $a \in R^n$.

Find  $E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf_i a_i\right)^{-k}$, for $k=1,2$